# Rewrite every url to go to directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, server

I have a folder structure like this

```
/first/second/{application}
```

And I would like that trough htaccess to load content from application without those two directories to appear. So `www.domain.com` would load `www.domain.com/first/second` and `www.domain.com/something/anything` would load `www.domain.com/first/second/something/anything`

I tried with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /first/second/index.php/$1 [L]` in htacces in root folder but without any success.

Comment: Perhaps you are getting an internal server error

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/first/second/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /first/second/$1`

Comment: This has to be adde to root folder or in 'second'?

Comment: In the root, which contain folder first

Comment: May be it is better to config server document root to /first/second/..., so you will not need rewrites